# How to redirect to webpage after the function triggered by an Ajax POST is completed

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm using Flask to build a WebApp. As part of the app I have some tables of data and buttons below that perform certain actions. The buttons work by fetching the `<tr>` elements of the table that have attribute `class="selected"`, and passing the value of the `id` attribute to a flask route.

This is the relevant javascript:

```
function submitDelete(action) {
  var data = buildIDPayload(); // which returns a dictionary in form {'ids':[1,2,3]}

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/delete",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    success: console.log('Data Submitted')
  });

  clearSelections();
};
```

and this is the Flask route that the data is sent to:

```
@app.route('/delete', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def delete_users():

    data = request.get_json(force=True)

    for i in data['ids']:
        u = User.query.filter_by(id=i).first()
        db.session.delete(u)
        db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('users'))
```

The database functionality all works fine, but I'm struggling to have the page refresh in an orderly way. If I set the refresh to occur as part of the success parameter in the ajax POST by setting it to `success: location.href = '/users'` then that refresh triggers *before* the flask route is done deleting the user that was passed to it, and this means that they're still present in the table on the refreshed page. On the other hand, if I don't use the `succcess` parameter to trigger a refresh and instead rely on `delete_users()` returning a flask `redirect`...nothing happens at all, it simply never refreshes (though the delete goes through fine).

So; how do I get either ajax or flask to redirect to a URL *after* the flask route that the ajax POSTed to is done processing it?

Comment: `success: console.log('Data Submitted')` is not how you give success a callback.  `success: function(){ console.log('Data Submitted'); }` is.  That console.log is going to execute as soon as the object is constructed to be given to $.ajax

Comment: @Taplar thanks for the tip. I forgot to push to git so I can't test that right now, but given the flask route does get executed as expected, I'm thinking this change won't affect the re-routing. Is that right or am I mistaken?